# patsubst in GNU Makefile using variable replacements

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given the following GNU Makefile code.

```
ENDING = '\.cpp'
OBJ = $(SOURCES:$(ENDING)=.o) # (does not work)
```

This does replace nothing, however,

```
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

does (for cpp files). Is there a way to tell patsubst *specific* endings? Or at least to replace all kind of endings, like below?

```
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.*=.o) # (does not work)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
ENDING = .cpp
OBJ = $(SOURCES:$(ENDING)=.o)
```

And this will replace all endings:

```
OBJ = $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: I was so focused on regexps that I did not recognize that \ could cause an issue :) Thanks a lot!